# Not able to connect BLOB storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have `Backup Contributor` role on `Microsoft Azure Storage Account`. I am  getting an error when trying to connect BLOB storage using `Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer` as follows:

`The Provided Connection String "url" does not have a complete configuration settings.`

Is there any workaround?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're connecting to a service using a SAS URL and experiencing this error:

·Verify that the URL provides the necessary permissions to read or list resources.
·Verify that the URL has not expired.
·If the SAS URL is based on an access policy, verify that the access policy has not been revoked.

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-explorer-troubleshooting#unable-to-retrieve-children-error-message).

**Workaround**：

1.Delete the data folder `%appData/StorageExplorer%` from your machine. Restart the storage explorer and [enter your credentials](https://github.com/CawaMS/StorageExplorerTroubleshootingGuide/blob/master/se-troubleshooting-guide.md#self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-chain). This may fix your problem.

2.While connecting to Azure Storage just check the box as **http** to connect the Azure Storage, making sure your host machine is in the safe network and continue to connect.